# Compress .mov video files on Python Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, video-processing, video-encoding

I have a Python/Django Ubuntu server (have all the tools of Python and Ubuntu at my disposal.)

How can I compress video files in the .mov format to lower compressions for a smaller file size?

Comment: FFmpeg or MEncoder don't do what you want?

Comment: This isn't specific to Python or Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PyFFMpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/) for that. [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/) may also work, but seem to get not developed further.

Answer (score 1):

Use ffmpeg : 745MB mov file of 4096x2023) to a 21MB mp4 file:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mov -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -acodec aac -vf scale=1024:576 output.mp4
```

Use it as command line or via python lib : https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Answer (score 0):

use thise lines with your videos with moviepy

https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.resize.html?highlight=resize#moviepy.video.fx.all.resize

myClip.resize( (460,720) ) # New resolution: (460,720)

myClip.resize(0.6) # width and heigth multiplied by 0.6

myClip.resize(width=800) # height computed automatically.

myClip.resize(lambda t : 1+0.02*t) # slow swelling of the clip